# Group data using foreach in php

Tags: php, json, if-statement, foreach

I have two json files, one has the leagues with `league id, league name` and the other has the `fixture id` and `league id`. How can I loop through fixtures and group them based on the league id and exclude/not show leagues with no fixtures which in this case is `League 202`.

I have tried using the code

```
foreach($league_group as $league) { 
    echo "League ID"; 
    foreach($fixture_list as $fixture){
        if($league->id == $fixture->league->id){
            echo $fixture->id."<br />";
        } else {
            echo "";
        }
    } 
}
```

**League File:**

```
"response": [
  
  {
    "league": {
      "id": 199,
      "name": "league 199",
      "type": "xxx",
      "logo": "xxxx"
    },
    "league": {
      "id": 200,
      "name": "league 200",
      "type": "xxx",
      "logo": "xxxx"
    },
    "league": {
      "id": 201,
      "name": "league 201",
      "type": "xxx",
      "logo": "xxxx"
    },
    "league": {
      "id": 202,
      "name": "league 202",
      "type": "xxx",
      "logo": "xxxx"
    }}
```

**Fitures file**

```
    "response": [
    {
      "fixture": {
        "id": 985816, 
        "date": "2023-04-27T00:00:00+00:00" 
        },
        "venue": {
          "id": 2356
        }
      },
      "league": {
        "id": 199,
        "name": "league 199"
     }
},
    {
      "fixture": {
        "id": 980016, 
        "date": "2023-04-27T00:00:00+00:00" 
        },
        "venue": {
          "id": 2354
        }
      },
      "league": {
        "id": 199,
        "name": "league 199"
     }
},
    {
      "fixture": {
        "id": 966816, 
        "date": "2023-04-27T00:00:00+00:00" 
        },
        "venue": {
          "id": 1145
        }
      },
      "league": {
        "id": 200,
        "name": "league 200"
     }
},
    {
      "fixture": {
        "id": 911116, 
        "date": "2023-04-27T00:00:00+00:00" 
        },
        "venue": {
          "id": 7380
        }
      },
      "league": {
        "id": 200,
        "name": "league 200"
     }
},
    {
      "fixture": {
        "id": 910006, 
        "date": "2023-04-27T00:00:00+00:00" 
        },
        "venue": {
          "id": 7380
        }
      },
      "league": {
        "id": 201,
        "name": "league 201"
     }
}
```

I want the output to look like this

```
league-id: 199
 - fixture-id: 985816
 - fixture-id: 980016
league-id: 200
 - fixture-id: 966816
 - fixture-id: 911116
league-id: 201
 - fixture id: 910006
*xxx exclude League 202 because it has no fixture xxxx*
```

Thank you

Comment: rather than echoing, build out another array, then loop over that to output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_filter()` to get all the fixtures for a particular league ID. If the resulting array is empty, don't print anything.

```
foreach ($league_group as $league) {
    $league_id = $league->id;
    $fixtures = array_filter($fixture_list, function($fixture) use ($league_id) {
        return $fixture->league->id == $league_id;
    });
    if ($fixtures) {
        echo "league-id: $league_id<br>";
        foreach ($fixtures as $fixture) {
            echo "-- fixture-id: $fixture->id<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "if", expecting ")"`

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it.